# how to display icon in center in ant design Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design `Button` and setting the icon but the icon is not displayed in center inside button.

[image]

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { DeleteOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

<Row>
  <Col span={2} style={{ padding: "5px" }} >
                                <Button
                                    type="primary"
                                    size="middle"
                                    shape="circle"
                                    danger
                                    icon={<DeleteOutlined />}

                                    onClick={() => deleteSkid(index)}
                                />
                            </Col>
</Row>
```

I also tried like this but there's no change.

```
<Row>
  <Col span={2} style={{ padding: "5px" }} >
            <Button
               type="primary"
               size="middle"
               shape="circle"
               danger
               onClick={() => deleteSkid(index)}
             >
                   <DeleteOutlined />
              </Button>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: Its works fine with me. Seems like you might have some CSS which was causing the issue or may be installed version might have bug.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using bootstrap or tailwind CSS?  Try adding this:

```
svg { vertical-align: baseline; }
```

Comment: For me this behavior started when I added Bootstrap to the project. I put your answer in my global style and worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { DeleteOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
 
<Button type="primary" danger shape="circle" icon={<DeleteOutlined />}></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a `padding-bottom` CSS property to the icon.

```
<LeftOutlined style={{ paddingBottom: "30px" }} />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add padding to the button itself and it will solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need import Button component from antd library

```
import { Button } from "antd";
```